# ¿Porqué este `for` no esta funionando si es lo mismo que el código que sustituye?

Tags: javascript

Esta función esta destinada a agregar eventos a varios `div`. De la segunda forma funciona pero quiero hacer mas corto el código, cuando lo convierto en `for` ya no funciona, no se agrega nada, se supone que debería funcionar así, o me estoy equivocando en como funcionan los ciclos `for`?

El código completo si se necesita ver es este
https://github.com/moorooba/simon/blob/master/simon3.html

```
function agregarEventosClick() {

    for( i = 0; i > colores.length; i++){
      colores[i].addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    }

    // colores.verde.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.amarillo.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.rojo.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.azul.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.blanco.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);

    // colores.box1.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.box2.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.box3.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
    // colores.box4.addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor);
  }
```

Comment: donde esta tu variable `colores`?, si no me equivoco debería de ser un *HTMLCollection*

Comment: El código debe incluirse en la pregunta, tratando de crear un [ejemplo mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) para poder tratar de ayudarte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los códigos no son equivalentes colores[0] no es lo mismo que colores.verde. En todo caso  podrías cambiar colores.verde por colores['verde']. Y en esto está la solución

```
for(color in colores){ colores[color].addEventListener("click", this.elegirColor) }
```

Como ves, se usa un bucle **for...in**, que permite recorrer las propiedades iterables de un objeto.